# How can I get position from a draggable marker in Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers

This is my current method

```
private void createNewMarker() {
    MarkerOptions AlarmMarker = new MarkerOptions();
    AlarmMarker.position(SearchedLocation).alpha(2).draggable(true)
            .snippet(MessageDataText).title(MessageDataTitle).zIndex(2.0f);
    mMap.addMarker(AlarmMarker);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SearchedLocation,10));
    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(@NonNull Marker marker) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(@NonNull Marker marker) {
            AlarmMarkerLatLng = AlarmMarker.getPosition();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), AlarmMarkerLatLng.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(@NonNull Marker marker) {

        }
    });


}
```

This only returns position that my marker was created on and not the updated one...

Comment: I noticed you have a habit of not following up on your questions. If an answer is provided that solves your problem, please mark it as the solution or at less answer your own question. The questions you ask are more for the next person.

Answer (score 0):

On your setOnMarkerDragListener, you want to use the local variable 'marker'. Don't try to get the value from outside of the scope.

```
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(@NonNull Marker marker) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(@NonNull Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), marker.getPostition.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(@NonNull Marker marker) {

        }
    });
```

The documentation has some really good examples: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker